# Strictly upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(F)$ be a strictly upper triangular matrix, I’m asked to construct $A$ such that $A^{n-1} \neq 0$.
I know that $A^n =0$, and $A^{n-1} = A^{-1}$, and I’m confused because a triangular matrix has an inverse only if it has no zeros on its main diagonal. How can $A$ have an inverse when it is a strictly upper triangular matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up a few things there. If $A^n = I$, then $A^{n-1} = A^{-1}$. But you have $A^n = 0$, so, as you already noticed, $A^{n-1} \neq A^{-1}$, in fact $A$ doesn't have an inverse in this case.